# Data repeating in R in two columns

Tags: r

In RStudio, I have input the data of my participants from IBEX, but after some formatting the data now looks like this in two columns:

```r
1 name xx. xx
2 age xx. xx
3 gender xx. xx
4 edu level xx xx
5 programme xx xx
6 name xx. xx
7 age xx. xx
8 gender xx. xx
9 edu level xx xx
10 programme xx xx
```

They keep on 'repeating' in two columns, and I don't know how to 'flip' the data by organising them according to the row element.

Let's assume the data frame is called 'df'.

I have tried:

`t(df)`

and something like:

```r
df2 <-df(t(df[-1]))
colnames(df2) <- df[,1]
```

then it just becomes a big row of continuous data repeating itself like:

```r
name age gender edu level programme name age gender edu level programme
xx   xx  xxx    xx  xx   xx      ...
```

I also didn't add the participant number yet because it seems to mess up more.

I would like my data to look like:

```r
subject   name     age.    gender  edu lv. programme
1.       xx       xx      xx   
2        xx       xx      xx.  
3        xx                    
4  
5
```

Thank you very much!

[image: Here's a picture of my data]

Answer (score 0):

Consider `ave` for running group count by indicator and then `reshape` for long to wide:

```
df$grp <- with(df, ave(V1, V2, FUN=seq_along))

rdf <- reshape(df, v.names = "V3", timevar = "V2", idvar = "grp",
               drop = "V1", sep="_", new.row.names = unique(df$grp), 
               direction = "wide")

colnames(rdf) <- gsub("V3_", "", colnames(rdf))

rdf
#   grp   name    age gender edu level programme
# 1   1 xx. xx xx. xx xx. xx    xx. xx    xx. xx
# 2   2 xx. xx xx. xx xx. xx    xx. xx    xx. xx
```

Data

```
txt <- '1 name "xx. xx"
2 age "xx. xx"
3 gender "xx. xx"
4 "edu level" "xx. xx"
5 programme "xx. xx"
6 name "xx. xx"
7 age "xx. xx"
8 gender "xx. xx"
9 "edu level" "xx. xx"
10 programme "xx. xx"'

df <- read.table(text = txt)
```